# Uploading large files leads to NoHttpResponseException

Tags: linux, jboss, server, connection-timeout

I have an J2EE application which has a REST endpoint that allows for uploading of files.  The application is deployed on jboss in a linux server.

All is good when the files is less than 4 mb in our server, but when I'm uploading a large file, I always end up with:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
```

Everything is working perfectly though when I'm testing locally (REST client calling local server running on my machine). I can even upload up to 10mb+ with no exceptions encountered.  But when I'll be hitting the linux server via REST client and the file is larger than 4mb, I'll get that NoHttpResponseException.  I've tried calling the upload endpoint within the linux server itself via a curl command, and it is working.

So, I'm guessing this isn't something specific in my codes or jboss setup, but an issue/configuration (server timeout setting perhaps?) on the linux server? Can anyone point me on the right direction?

All help appreciated. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: Have you setup the Connection: keep-alive header and setup the timeout ?

Comment: When you say you've called the upload endpoint within the Linux server using curl, was that attaching a payload (`POST` data) over 4MB in size? Or, was it just a simple curl to check the endpoint responds via HTTP?

Comment: Can you provide code for how you initialize the http client? Because the default clients have default timeouts set, when they are not changed the connections after that timeout are marked as stale and cleaned up

Comment: maybe the upload filesize is limited try     <multipart-config>  
      <max-file-size>5120000</max-file-size>  
      <max-request-size>5120000</max-request-size>  
    </multipart-config>   in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to some piece of networking equipment or configuration between your server and the remote client from which you perform a large upload, IF you are telling us that the large uploads via local `curl` work on both your server and local development environment.

Because you have not described your setup beyond the application code, we can't help beyond:

1. Have you set `keep-alive` on the request, and ensured all load balancers and similar equipment will respect the request duration / not kill TCP? It is highly unlikely that no `Request Timeout` response would come from an HTTP-based piece of networking equipment, so look for TCP issues.
2. Have you verified that there is not a hard, chronological timeout setting on the local machine? It seems unlikely that you would get NO response from a `Request Timeout` originated from an HTTP server, but this could also be it.
3. Are you able to verify smaller requests work from the remote location? If not, then it could even be as simple as:
   (A) Missing stateful firewall rule on the server
   (B) You aren't binding to the correct network interface like `0.0.0.0` on the server and only on a loopback/local interface
   (C) Bad  stateless rule for outbound transmission like a missing Network ACL rule: inbound but not outbound